# Pytorch-index on multiple dimension tensor in a batch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Given a 1-d tensor:

```
A = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

suppose we have some "indexer tensor"

```
ind1 = torch.tensor([3, 0, 1])
ind2 = torch.tensor([[3, 0], [1, 2]])
```

as we run `A[ind1]` & `A[ind2]`

we get results `tensor([4, 1, 2])` & `tensor([[4, 1],[2, 3]])`
which is the same shape of the indexed tensor (ind1 and ind2) and its value are mapped from tensor A.

I want to ask how can I **index on higher dimension tensors**?

---

**Currently I have one solution**:

For a N-d tensor A, suppose we have the indexer tensor IND,
IND is like `[[i11, i12, ... i1N], [i21, i22, ... i2N], ...[iM1, i22, ... iMN]`, where M is the number of indexed elements.
We can divide IND into N tensors, where

```
IND_1 = torch.tensor([i11, i21, ... iM1])
...
IND_N = torch.tensor([i1N, i2N, ... iMN])
```

as we run `A[IND_1, ... IND_N]`, we got `tensor(v1, v2, ... vM)`

Example:

```
A = tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]])  # [2 * 2 * 2]
ind1 = tensor([1, 0, 1])
ind2 = tensor([1, 1, 0])
ind3 = tensor([0, 1, 0])
A[ind1, ind2, ind3]
=> tensor([7, 4, 5])
# and the good thing is you can control the shape of result tensor by modifying the inds' shape.
ind1 = tensor([[0, 0], [1, 0]])
ind2 = tensor([[1, 1], [0, 1]])
ind3 = tensor([[0, 1], [0, 0]])
A[ind1, ind2, ind3]
=> tensor([[3, 4],[5, 3]])  # same as inds' shape
```

Anyone has more elegant solutions?

Comment: Your first example seem to be incorrect, `A[ind1, ind2, ind3]` yields `tensor([7, 4, 5])`, instead of `tensor([3, 4, 5])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### 1- Manual approach using unraveled indices on flattened input.

If you want to index on an arbitrary number of axes (all axes of `A`) then one straightforward approach is to flatten all dimensions and unravel the indices. Let's assume that `A` is 3D and we want to index it using a stack of `ind1`, `ind2`, and `ind3`:

```
>>> ind = torch.stack((ind1, ind2, ind3))
```

You can first unravel the indices using `A`'s strides:

```
>>> unraveled = torch.tensor(A.stride()) @ ind.flatten(1)
```

Then flatten `A`, index it with `unraveled` and reshape to the final form:

```
>>> A.flatten()[unraveled].reshape_as(ind[0])
```

---

##### 2- Using a simple split of `ind`.

You can actually perform the same operation using [`torch.chunk`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.chunk.html#torch.chunk):

```
>>> A[ind.chunk(len(ind))][0]
```

Or alternatively `torch.split` which is identical:

```
>>> A[ind.split(1)][0]
```

---

##### 3- Initial answer for single-axis indexing.

Let's take a minimal multi-dimensional example with `A` being a 2-D tensor defined as:

```
>>> A = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                      [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

From your description of the problem:

> the same shape of index tensor and its value are mapped from tensor `A`.

Then the indexer tensor would require to have the same shape as the indexed tensor `A`, since this one is no longer flat. *Otherwise, what would the result of `A` (shaped `(2, 4)`) indexed by `ind1` (shape `(3,)`) be?*

If you are indexing on a single dimension then you can utilize [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html):

```
>>> A.gather(1, ind2)
tensor([[4, 1],
        [6, 7]])
```

---

Comment: Thank you Ivan for your reply. I need to admit my original description "the same shape of indexer tensor", I will edit my question. I don't think gather is what I want, I need to index on multiple dimension just like A[x, y] but process in a vector form, instead of using for loop. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @Thyme, I have edited my answer

Comment: thanks a lot, that's very comprehensive!